# How change veevalidate language without webpack .net Core 3.1 web Application

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vee-validate

in my _layout.cshtml veevalidate was referenced like :
~/lib/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.js in script

in my create.cshtml page :

How can  change default language to french without webpack

Comment: Hope this will help you http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/localization.html

Comment: thanks for your post, veevalidate 3 was used and i cant import file in my <script> import Vue from 'vue';

Comment: in my _layout.cshtml :
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <script src="~/lib/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.js"></script>
    <script defer src="~/lib/fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script>
    Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider);    

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#creationUserAction',
        data: {
            menu: [
                {
                    name: "Compte windows"
                }
            ],
            windowsLoginName: ""
        },
        beforeCreate() {
            this.firstLoad = true;
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.firstLoad = false;
        },
        created: function () {

        },
        methods: {
            
        }
    })
</script>

Comment: Try to setup it when you creating validation provider component